# Fail to connect two sockets which are bound with two public IP address in a server

Tags: sockets, tcp

I tried to setup a XSTUNT server on Linux(http://www.cis.nctu.edu.tw/~gis87577/xDreaming/XSTUNT/index.html) to do p2p traversal, but failed. I read the source code of it. I found the application creates two TCP sockets and then bind them to the two public IP addresses respectively. The remote client is able to connect only one of the public IP address.

So I wrote a simple server application to test this environment. 
On the remote client, I use this two commands 
"nc [public IP_A] [PORT]" and 
"nc [public IP_B] [PORT]" 
to try to connect to the server. Only one is successful, while the other fail. I have sniffer the traffic on the client, the nc which is failed can not get "SYN-ACK" package from the server. Is it the route problem? My two public interfaces do NOT have special gateway. Because I use PPPoE to connect to the Internet. So I just get ppp0 and ppp1. I don't know how to change the route table if the route table cause this problem.

However, If I do these two command on the server which is running my sever application, both commands are successful.  Who can tell me why?

NOTE: I compiled this server application on Windows with cygwin. The result is the same.

Here is the code of my server application

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVPORT 3333 /* Listen Port */
#define BACKLOG 10 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int sockfd[2],client_fd; 
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr; 
  struct sockaddr_in remote_addr; /* client socket info */
  int sin_size;
  int maxfd;
  fd_set rfds;
  int i;

  if(argc != 3)
    {
      printf("Usage: %s <IP_1> <IP_2>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    if ((sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
      perror("socket error！"); exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Create sockfd[%d] = %d\n", i, sockfd[i]);
   }
  }

  // set the first Socket
  my_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_port=htons(SERVPORT);
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
  bzero(&(my_addr.sin_zero),8);

  if (bind(sockfd[0], (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error！");
    exit(1);
  }

  // set the second Socket
  my_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_port=htons(SERVPORT);
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
  bzero(&(my_addr.sin_zero),8);
  if (bind(sockfd[1], (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error！");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    if (listen(sockfd[i], BACKLOG) == -1) {
      perror("listen error！");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  if(sockfd[0] > sockfd[1])
    maxfd = sockfd[0];
  else
    maxfd = sockfd[1];

  while(1) {

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd[0], &rfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd[1], &rfds);

    printf("waiting client\n");
    select(maxfd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd[0], &rfds))
    {
      printf("sockfd[0](%s) is readable\n", argv[1]);

      if ((client_fd = accept(sockfd[0], (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, (socklen_t *)&sin_size)) == -1) {
        perror("accept error");
        continue;
      }
    }
    else if(FD_ISSET(sockfd[1], &rfds))
    {
      printf("sockfd[1](%s) is readable\n", argv[2]);
      if ((client_fd = accept(sockfd[1], (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, (socklen_t *)&sin_size)) == -1) {
        perror("accept error");
        continue;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("select error\n");
      continue;
    }

    printf("received a connection from %s:%d\n\n", (char *)inet_ntoa(remote_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(remote_addr.sin_port));
    if (!fork()) { /* child process */
      if (send(client_fd, "Hello, you are connected!\n", 26, 0) == -1)
        perror("send error！");
      close(client_fd);
      exit(0);
    }
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```